# May an Indian citizen with Italian residence travel to the UK without a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian Citizen living in Italy with/on Resident Permit. Can I travel UK for few days to meet my friends without Visa in this case as UK is part of EU. I have already travelled to Germany & Croatia with my Indian Passport & Resident Permit via Road & Air as well.

Answer (score 18):

No. You are able to travel to Germany and Croatia because Germany is a part of the Schengen area, and Croatia is in the process of joining it, and accepts visas issued by Schengen member states. To travel to the UK you will need to apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa), as the UK is not a part of the Schengen area. If in doubt, feel free to check [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

As noted in the comment below, it is important to understand that the European Union and the Schengen agreement are not the same. The EU is a trade and customs union that allows freedom of movement for EU citizens - this still requires a passport, for example, when travelling from the UK to France, which are both in the EU. The Schengen agrement abolishes all internal borders between the member states. You should however carry your passport and Schengen visa/residence permit (as a non-EU citizen) or your national ID card as an EU citizen. As an example, Ireland is an EU member that is not a part of the Schengen area, while Switzerland is, but is not an EU/EEA member.

Comment: @B.Liu SgrA does exactly that in the first sentence of the second paragraph of the Answer.

Comment: unfortunately, even Schengen does not mean a passport is not required: EU citizens are still obliged to carry one, or another valid ID document, when travelling cross-border. Border control can also be temporarily reestablished between member states during special events, or, as we saw it happening in the recent past, to hinder or redirect migration.

Comment: @David The comment was made before the second paragraph is added to the answer. As the comment requesting to "spell out the difference between the EU and Schengen" is since addressed, I will now delete it. Thanks for the ping.

Comment: I agree with dlatikay: you always need to bring proper documents (passport+residency permit) when travelling to Schengen countries. Its illegal not to so so. Sometimes these documents are checked at flight checkin and you will be denied boarding (worst case only denied boarding on your way back)

Comment: I'll correct my answer so it reflects the fact that you should always carry your passport, even though there is often no passport control.